# Touch Focus Changing After Showing DatePicker In a Popup

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uidatepicker

I have a UIViewController. In my view (xib), I have a UIButton and a UIToolBar. On "Touch Up Inside", I have the following:

```
    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ec];
nc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];
```

"ec" is a UITableViewController. For this view (xib), I have three rows that consists of three text fields. In one text field, I'm setting the "inputView" to a UIDatePicker. If I put focus on this text field the datepicker shows up as it suppose to. When I set the focus on another text field, the keyboard shows up. But when I close the popup, it seems like the UIButton and UIToolBar right navigation button isn't working. Actually it is, but I have to click about an inch above the control to trigger the popup again. What gives?!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late post but found out the application was recalculating the view coordinates which threw it off. After fixing this, all is good.